# SOAP returns error "value can not be invalid. parametername document"

Tags: php, soap

I'm using the PHP SOAP client to perform this request:

```
$params = array(
    'MethodParameters' => array(
        'UNI_OnHand_AIF' => array(
            'DocPurpose' => 'Original',
            'UNI_Onhand' => array(
                'AxdEntity_UNI_Onhand' => array(
                    'ItemBarCode' => '12345678912',
                    'OnHand' => 0,
                    'RecId' => 0,
                    'RecVersion' => 0,
                    'class' => 'entity',
                    'action' => 'create',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In WCFstorm I got the desired result but with PHP SOAP client I got a fatal error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Waarde kan niet ongeldig zijn. Parameternaam: document

I don't understand the error because there isn't a (not optional nor required) parameter 'document'. Due to security reasons I can't give much more info but I've done other soap call's (with other parameters and other wsdl's) with the same script which all succeeded.

Comment: So you are probably missing that required parameter...

Comment: Like I wrote: is not an optional nor required parameter.

Comment: The error returned is sent to you by the responding server. If you are working with the wsdl, try to find out if there is a parameter `document` listed in there. If not, refer to the party supplying the SOAP server and supply them with the error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
I installed [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and entered in a new project the wsdl address checking the option "Create sample request"

You will see for each action the complete structure. You can compare with the array you are sending and check where is the problem

Hope this helps